# Python CGI to invoke another CGI script that runs a sensor in Raspberry

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, cgi

I have a python CGI program (says: scrip1), that I am using to set values for some variable for another python CGI script (says: script 2) using web browser. I am using the script 2 to run a Lidar Sensor.  The problem is I can set the variable in script 2 using script 1. But script 2 is not executing after receiving variable. Script 2 suppose to start my sensor. Any possible solutions. (I would like to stick on CGI scripts)

```
#script 1

#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import cgi
import cgitb
print("Content-Type: text/html\r\n")
print("")
print'''<html>
<head><title>Form to enter sleep time</title></head>
<body>

<form action="/cgi-bin/test.py" method="post">

    <html><label> enter sleep time</label>

    <input type="number" name="sleeptime"/>

    <input type="submit" name ="Submit" "></form>

</body>

</html>'''


#### second script is######

#!/usr/bin/python

import os

import cgi

import cgitb

import smbus

import time

print("Content-Type: text/html\r\n")

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

sleeptime = form.getfirst("sleeptime")    #getting value from script 1 (form data)

#script to run the Lidar is as follows#

bus=smbus.SMBus(1)

addr=0x62

while True:
    bus.write_byte_data(0x62,0x00, 0x04)  

    val_high=bus.read_byte_data(0x62,0x0f)  

    val_low=bus.read_byte_data(0x62,0x10)   

    dist_cm=val_high*256+val_low

    print (dist_cm , " cm ")

    time.sleep(sleeptime)
```

Comment: Without code we can't help.

Comment: please check my updated question @Cid

Comment: You have put both the scripts here in a very confusing manner. Half of the first script is the first code block, and rest in second (as if it is part of the second script). Please correct it first.

Comment: @AhmadBilal , sorry... I didn't notice it. made changes.!

Comment: Done the corrections... Any possible solution.. Please

Answer (score 0):

The extension of the first file is .py as well? Have you tried using .cgi extension (with contents remaining the same)

Comment: Yes. I tried. Didn't work. I can pass variable. But second script is not executing after the line (sleeptime = form.getfirst("sleeptime")...  :(

Comment: Perhaps it is a encoding issue. Try using a common charset like 'us-ascii'. Perhaps, the values are being received but not understood.